# MarkupExtension in Windows.Resources will fail Control with x:Shared="False" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

My code is as follows:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <Window.Resources>

        <local:ClassInheritME x:Key="class" />

        <TextBox x:Key="box" x:Shared="False" />
        
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource box}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource box}" />
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource box}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the class `ClassInheritME` is a plain class inheriting `MarkupExtension`, which looks like:

```cs
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(ClassInheritME))]
    internal class ClassInheritME : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

If everything works fine, there will be three individual `TextBox` in the `StackPanel`.

The phenomeon is, by writing the `ClassInheritME` in `Window.Resources`, the `TextBox` with `x:Shared="False"` seems not working, as there is only be one `TextBox` visible since they are referencing the same one.

However, as long as I move the `ClassInheritME` instance to anywhere not at the beginning of the `Window.Resources` clause, then the problem is solved, and the `x:Shared="False` works fine by showing all three `TextBox`.

What is the reason of this? Does `MarkupExtension` have some limitation, and writing such a subclass in a `ResourceDictionary` somehow violates the rule?

Comment: Why are you not using an itemscontrol with an item template for your repeated UI? Which I guess is not just a textbook in your real app.

Comment: What's you markup extension intended to achieve?

Comment: @Andy I simplified my code. The real scenario is more complicated and meaningful. I just want to show the phenomenon with this simple code snippet